# Как выполнить PHP код в файле и вернуть сгенерированную разметку?

Tags: php

Есть `.php` файл и в нем содержится разметка со вставками `<?php echo $foo; ?>`. Я получаю этот файл в контроллере таким образом

```php
$content = file_get_contents('/path/to/file.php');
```

Ясное дело что он когда будет читать файл не выполнит PHP код, а просто прочитает его как строку *(хотя при использовании* `file_get_contents()` *он обарачивает PHP код в HTML комментарии, но тем не менее)*. Как сделать чтобы при **чтении файла выполнялся PHP код который в него вставлен**, и после я смог получить вставленный им контент?

`include, require...` не подходят, поскольку мне нужно **именно записать в переменную выполненное содержимое файла**

Comment: [curl](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/curl.examples.php#88055)

Comment: [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ob_start();
include_once('/path/to/file.php');
$content = ob_get_clean();
```